# Error with Enterprise gateway in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

Getting an error on the Enterprise Gateway

> The following exception occured while the managed iDbconnection
>   interface was being used the keyword isn't supported: Version

What can be done to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, and apparently the cause this error is when you create a manual table by using the 'Enter data' option. I had a data table with just one row but Power BI didn't like that, and kept giving the same error on each refresh attempt. Removing the the table altogether eliminated this error.

http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/The-keyword-isn-t-supported-version/td-p/23372

Thanks

Kaz